# AngularJS HTTP post method not working with web service running on localhost

Tags: angularjs, web-services

i have started AngularJS 4 days ago and this question is answered many times but i cant correct my problem, here us my code

**userType.html**

```
<div ng-controller="formuserTypesController">
        User Type: <input type="text" ng-model="title" style="margin-bottom: 10px;"><br/>
        Description: <input type="text" ng-model="description" style="margin-bottom: 10px;"><br/>
        <button ng-keyup="add($event)" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">Submit Form</button>

        <h3>{{answer}}</h3>   
        <h3>{{displayres}}</h3>
        <br/>   
</div>

<div ng-controller="userTypesController">
    <!--div data-ng-repeat="ut in usertypes|limitTo:10 "-->
    <div data-ng-repeat="ut in usertypes ">
        <b>ID:</b> {{ ut.id }}<br/>
        <b>User Type:</b> {{ ut.usertype_title }}<br/>
        <b>Description: </b> {{ ut.usertype_desc }}<br/><br/>
    </div>
    <br/>
</div>
```

**and controller.js**

```
eventsApp.controller('formuserTypesController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 
    function($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
        $scope.title = '';
        $scope.description = '';
        $scope.add = function( event ) {
            if( event.keyCode == 13 ) {
                $scope.answer = 'Posting data . . .';
                //$http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: '/developer/user_type/',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { usertype_title: $scope.title, usertype_desc: $scope.description },              
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8' },
                    }).
                    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        $scope.displayres = data
                        $scope.answer = 'Data has been successfully posted.';
                        //console.log(data);
                    }).
                    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        $scope.displayres = data
                        $scope.answer = 'Posting data was unsuccessful.';
                        //console.log(data);
                      });                                       
            }
        }       
}]);
```

i cant get it working using any solution provided on stackoverflow, any help will be appreciated

**console**

```
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[08/Dec/2014 15:58:00] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1265
[08/Dec/2014 15:58:01] "GET /static/js/controllers.js HTTP/1.1" 200 2541
[08/Dec/2014 15:58:01] "GET /static/js/partials/userType.html HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[08/Dec/2014 15:58:01] "GET /developer/user_type/?format=json HTTP/1.1" 200 210
[08/Dec/2014 16:00:02] "GET /developer/user_type/ HTTP/1.1" 200 11576
[08/Dec/2014 16:36:33] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1265
[08/Dec/2014 16:36:33] "GET /static/js/app.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[08/Dec/2014 16:36:33] "GET /static/js/controllers.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[08/Dec/2014 16:36:33] "GET /static/js/partials/userType.html HTTP/1.1" 200 688
[08/Dec/2014 16:36:33] "GET /developer/user_type/?format=json HTTP/1.1" 200 210
```

Comment: What is your back-end code? What is your response? Maybe it's just routing issue? If you get 404, it's probably routing

Comment: nothing appears get method works but post method is not even showing in console with any kind of response

Comment: Does your console show the out going POST request actually being made?

Comment: only GET mehtods are listed POST method doesnt appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in **controller.js** change these two lines

```
eventsApp.controller('formuserTypesController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 
    function($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
```

to

```
eventsApp.controller('formloginController', function($scope, $http) {
```

and also **addition of csrftoken in webservice**, resolved my issue.

in **views.py**

```
from django.core.context_processors import csrf

def index(request):
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    return render_to_response('index.html', c)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's due to CORS restrictions.

See:

- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/
- [Angular $http.get to localhost, always returns 404. 200 in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22148105/angular-http-get-to-localhost-always-returns-404-200-in-browser)

Comment: why it would be a cors issue?

Comment: $http.get method is working fine, but POST method is not showing any response in console.

Comment: turning off all authentication still GET method works but POST doesn't