# GET request to localhost producing error 404 on Postman

Tags: angular, get, localhost, postman

I am trying to send a GET request to http://localhost:4200/login from Postman but keep getting Error 404, even though the URL is accessible from the browser. http://localhost:4200 also works fine with a state of 200 but adding "/login" produces an error. I am serving an Angular application on this port.

Comment: are you sure that you need to use postman to access the angular app route via postman? usualy it's used for working with requests to backend endpoints

Comment: I intend to implement load testing using locust.io but when I tried using it the requests were failing for the same reason. So I shifted to postman to try and debug the issue but haven't had any luck. Also I have deployed this app and sending a request to https://<deployedapp>/login works fine. I only get the error 404 when using localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like CORS
issue .

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22151921/6793637

Could you try adding

Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*

Header to postman

**Note*** your app should be set to accept only origin from specific domain not wild card in production